Facebook graph API error code: 368: "We limit how often you can post, comment or do other things in a given amount of time in order to help ..."
I'm trying to make a bot that replies to facebook comments on my page's livestream. Unfortunately, after a few replies, Facebook send back an error message with code 368 and I can only send more replies after a few seconds. The full message is:
We limit how often you can post, comment or do other things in a given amount of time in order to help protect the community from spam. You can try again later

The API I'm using is /${page_id}/comments
There seem to be a lot of people got into my issue as well: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/938590201317189

Is it the same/similar reply every time? This isn't a bug; Facebook just doesn't like that you're posting repeatedly with similar messages. They correctly identify it as spammy.

While your point is worth considering, I think this question is worth asking because the issue appeared suddenly and without any announcements to developers or updating in documents. Some guys in the thread I attached have their program working smoothly for years before this happened. Plus, my program was replying to just about 10 - 20 comments per minute when this issue arised

Facebook never announces changes to spam algorithms/mitigations of this nature. 10-20 identical comments per minute is absolutely the sort of thing Facebook cracks down on.

Just out of curiosity, why don't they have an option for setting a role like moderator for a page that can perform any actions within their page without restriction?

Because even moderators can do spammy things. It's not your page, really; it's Facebook's.
